# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode)

Tags: flutter, xcode, debugging, openssl, cocoapods

I have a problem that I am trying to solve, and thus far I have tried everything but it doesn't work, so I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

I am trying to debug my flutter application, and I have linked it with firebase . So my flutter application needs cocoapods and openssl.

I have installed those 2, but whenever I try to debug my application I get this error :

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode) : 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
Development/app_name/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/tsi/ssl/key_logging/ssl_key_logging.h:22:9.

But if I go to this folder, I can see that the #include <openssl/ssl.h> is there.

How can I fix this?

I tried downloading again openssl, and I want my app to debug normally. If I remove everything related to firebase, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two days later, I found a solution:

1. In the console, navigate to the ios folder:

`cd ios`

2. Delete the file:

`rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock`

3. Next, enter the command:

`pod cache clean --allpod`

4. and finally:

`pod install`

source: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/3203#issuecomment-743789416